# JavaScript OO class with listener callbacks

Tags: javascript, object, listener

## Background

I have been playing around with setting up my own JavaScript base Objects for a little project. I wanted to be able to set up some simple objects that my more complicated objects could inherit functionality from.

I have been following a few tutorials (http://desalasworks.com/article/object-oriented-javascript-inheritance/) online and have the basic extends behaviour I need, see the code section of this question for the base framework setup.

I have a class TestModel that inherits functionality from Model. I can create two new instance like so:

```
var test_model_1 = new TestModel();
var test_model_2 = new TestModel();
```

I can then set some data on them:

```
test_model_1.set({test:'Test1'});
test_model_2.set({test:'Test2'});
```

I can get the results for both objects:

```
test_model_1.get() //test will = Test1
test_model_2.get() //test will = Test2
```

I now add a listener to test_model_1 only:

```
test_model_1.addListener(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

and call set on test_model_2:

```
test_model_2.set({test:'Some data that should not be seen in the console.log'});
```

test_model_1 listener is getting triggered and sending the data to the console log. As the listener was only added to the test_model_1 object and the set was called on the test_model_2 object, this shouldn't happen.

## Question

What is wrong with my Model class that is allowing all listeners to be called whenever set is called on any instance of the class?

## Code

### Object.extends

```
Object.extend = function (superClass, definition) {

    var subClass = function () {
    };

    // Our constructor becomes the 'subclass'
    if (definition.constructor !== Object) {
        subClass = definition.constructor;
    }

    subClass.prototype = new superClass();
    for (var prop in definition) {
        if (prop != 'constructor')
            subClass.prototype[prop] = definition[prop];
    }

    // Keep track of the parent class
    // so we can call its constructor too
    subClass.superClass = superClass;
    return subClass;
};
```

### Model

```
Model = Object.extend(Object, {

    data: {},

    listener: [],

    constructor: function (data) {
        var root = this;
        this.data = data;
    },

    get: function () {
        return this.data;
    },

    set: function (data) {
        this.data = data
        var arrayLength = this.listener.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            this.listener[i](data);
        }
    },

    addListener: function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            this.listener.push(callback);
        }

    }
});
```

### TestModel

```
TestModel = Object.extend(Model, {

    constructor: function () {
        TestModel.superClass.call(this, {test: 'some default data'});
    },

    addListener: function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            this.listener.push(callback);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Objects on the `.prototype` are shared among instances. You want each instance to have its own `data` object and `listener` array, so assign those to each instance in the constructor so that they're not shared.

Comment: @cookiemonster can you tell me what this.listener[i](data);  do ?

Comment: The `listeners` property references an Array which holds the event listener functions for the object. So when it comes time to trigger an event, he looks up the `listeners` array and invokes all the functions stored inside. So `this.listeners` is the Array, `this.listeners[i]` is getting the array member at the `i` index, and `this.listeners[i](data)` is invoking the function found at that index, and passing it the `data`.

Answer (score 1):

This was a simple fix, I needed to create an instance of listener in the Model constructor, if this is not done listener will be on the .prototype object scope and shared between all objects that extend it.

## Fixed Model

```
Model = Object.extend(Object, {

    data: {},

    listener: [],

    constructor: function (data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.listener = []; //set up listener for this instance
    },

    get: function () {
        return this.data;
    },

    set: function (data) {
        this.data = data
        var arrayLength = this.listener.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            this.listener[i](data);
        }
    },

    addListener: function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            this.listener.push(callback);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what this.listener[i](data); means ??